# using Go Routines and Wait group

Tags: go, goroutine

I am trying to using Goroutine in my APIs. I need to check the method I am using is correct or whether it need any improvement .

I am creating REST-APIs using go. using SQL-boiler also.

In many of my APIs I am using some other functions like, Notification sending using AWS, Email Sending using AWS, Mailchimp integrations.

Some APIS using these 3 features other than our database activity.

So I found out it takes a time in API for displaying the result..  Then I found Goroutine and wait-group.

Here I don't want to take  time for complete my apis. But I want to excecated the other functionality behind code.

So I just checked and I am confused about goroutine and wait-group.
When I using wait-group  in 3 functionality I understand that.. after completing all functionality api is giving response.

But when using goroutine API is easily giving response and other functionalities are doing in background..

using go routine API is taking less time than Waitgroup..

Is this correct ?.
The way I am approaching is correct or not ? Or anything is missing in my work flow ?

```
{
if impartWealthIds != "" {
        impartWealthIds = strings.Trim(impartWealthIds, ",")
        updateUser := fmt.Sprintf(`Update user 
        set deleted_at='%s' ,
         email=CONCAT(email, "-", impart_wealth_id),
         screen_name=CONCAT(screen_name, "-", impart_wealth_id),
         deleted_by_admin=true 
         where impart_wealth_id in(%s);
        `, golangDateTime, impartWealthIds)

        query = updateUser
    }
    _, err = queries.Raw(query).ExecContext(ctx, m.db)
    m.logger.Info(query)
    if err != nil {
        m.logger.Error("query failed", zap.Any("query", err))
        return err
    }
    go func() {
        for _, user := range userDetails {
            email := fmt.Sprintf("%s-%s", user.ImpartWealthID, user.Email)
            userUp := management.User{
                Email: &email,
            }
            err = mngmnt.User.Update(*&user.AuthenticationID, &userUp)
            if err != nil {
                m.logger.Error("Auth update failed", zap.Any("user.Email", user.Email), zap.Any("query", err))
            }
        }
    }()
    go impart.UserDemographicsUpdate(ctx, m.db, true, true)
        if user.R.MemberHiveHives != nil {
            if user.R.MemberHiveHives[0].NotificationTopicArn.String != "" {
                go func() {
                    err := m.notificationService.UnsubscribeTopicForAllDevice(ctx, user.ImpartWealthID, user.R.MemberHiveHives[0].NotificationTopicArn.String)
                    if err != nil {
                        m.logger.Error("SubscribeTopic", zap.String("DeviceToken", user.R.MemberHiveHives[0].NotificationTopicArn.String),
                            zap.Error(err))
                    }
                }()
            }
        }
    go impart.UserDemographicsUpdate(ctx, m.db, true, true)
    return "success"
}
```

here APi return success after database operation and other goroutines will be run in background

I have an another double also

if I am using a for-loop of users . and I need to Update some data for each user..

```
for _, user := range userDetails {
// calling auth 0
// calling mailchimp
// calling aws
}
```

I need to update data for each user

then my question is which is the best method for using goroutine??

method-1

```
for _, user := range userDetails {
        go calling auth 0
        go calling mailchimp
        go calling aws

        }
```

method - 2

```
  for _, user := range userDetails {
        go func(user *dbmodels.User) {
            // calling auth 0
            // calling mailchimp
            // calling aws
        }(user)
            }
```

which one is the best method?

Comment: Yes, the elapsed time to start the goutiness is less than the elapsed time to start the goroutines and wait for the goroutines to complete.

Comment: @PenélopeStevens , what you are saying is, we need to use waitgroup ?. I felt taking time on using waitgroup more than goroutine

Comment: The only time WaitGroup takes is the time the goroutine take to finish, i.e it takes no time if the goroutines have all called `Done()`. If you need to wait for the goroutines to finish, then waiting is a matter of correctness, not execution time.

Comment: @MiaMia Does the application need to return an error to the caller if there's a failure in one of the goroutines? If so, the application should wait on the goroutines and get an error status for each goroutine ([errgroup](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sync/errgroup) may be useful for this).

Answer (score 0):

Both of the suggested methods may not work for the large amount of data, both the methods will create 3N and N goroutines respectively which is sufficient to crash you system for large number of users.
Using a worker pool would be the best solution here with any method that feels convenient to you. That way you will be able to limit calls.
Reference: https://gobyexample.com/worker-pools